# model relationships dependant on others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relational-database

I'm trying to do something, I'm not sure if it's possible...

I need a User, who needs a Manager. BUT, if the User has a Pod, their manager can be derived from the Pod.owner (in fact, it must be).

So, something like:

```
class User
   belongs_to :pod, optional: true 
   belongs_to :manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "report_id", optional: true
   ???
end
```

Essentially, if the :pod exists, a manager is not needed because :manager will be pod.owner.

Because I'm an idiot I tried to monkey patch it thusly:

```
def manager
   (pod.nil?) ?  manager :  pod.owner
end
```

I'll leave it as an exercise to the user as to why this is nonsense :D

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting design problem in my opinion and I'm sure there are plenty of valid solutions. Here is the first that comes to my mind. Instead of overriding the manager method that's defined by the association, I would rename the `manager` association to `direct_manager`. I makes its role explicit. Then, you can define `manager` as it's no longer defined. The end result would be:

```
class User
  belongs_to :pod, optional: true 
  belongs_to :direct_manager, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "report_id", optional: true

  def manager
    return pod.owner if pod.present?
    direct_manager
  end
end
```

```

Note that I used a guard clause instead of the ternary operator, but it's only a matter of personal taste on the code style.

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much

Comment: Hi Sophie - or anyone else who see this - I now need to overload manager= to create users... I've tried `def manager= (user); direct_manager = user; save; end` but this doesn't work. I need to be able to `User.create!(manager: boris)` and have it assign direct_manager...

Comment: Figured it out! `def manager= (user); self[:report_id] = user.id; end` Thanks again for the direction.